# How To use the gspread backoffclient in the authorize method to avoid quota exceeded error?

Tags: google-sheets-api, gspread

I tried with the following code.

```
    scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("credentials_g4a.json",scope)

    client = gspread.authorize(creds, client_factory=gspread.client.BackoffClient)
```

It throws the unexpected keyword error:

authorize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'client_factory'.

Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: When I saw [the document of `classgspread.client.BackoffClient(auth, session=None)`](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/client.html#gspread.client.BackoffClient), it's `This Client is not production ready yet. Use it at your own risk !`. So, for example, about `avoid quota exceeded error`, can you provide your script for occurring it? In order to avoid "quota exceeded error", how about confirming whether there is a modification part of the script for using Sheets API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi in order to use this new beta feature, you must have `gspread` in version 5.5.0

Make sure you installed the minimum version. You can make sure of that using the following command:

```
python -m pip install gspread==5.5.0
```

The error message you have suggested that you have an older version of gspread that does not handle that new beta feature.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I will try it in a few other ways and let you know if the backoff works when the quota exceed happens.

Comment: It will help, but it won't solved it, at some point if you keep sending requests you'll reach the quota. Keep in mind, your script will take much longer to execute as it waits longer and longer between each retry .

Comment: What is the best approach for this apart from increasing the quota? Even google support suggested using Backoffclient or to use a batch update.